# PowerShell error: Set-AzureDeployment : CurrentStorageAccountName is not set

Tags: azure, powershell-3.0

I need deploy package (mvc site) from powershel script to azure. But when I start script, I see that it doesn't work. The powershell show that Azure Cloud Service deploy script finished, but in fact doesn't any change.  Can you help me to fix it?
This is my powershell command:

```
        PS C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> PowerShell C:\scripts\WindowsAzur
    e\PublishCloudApp.ps1 -environment Production -enableDeploymentUpgrade 1 -servic
    eName testLocalAzure -storageAccountName testcloudservice -packageLocation C:\dr
    ops\app.publish\WindowsAzureC.cspkg -cloudConfigLocation C:\drops\app.publish\Se
    rviceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg -subscriptionDataFile C:\scripts\WindowsAzure\def
    aul.publishsettings
    1/13/2014 1:12 AM - Azure Cloud Service deploy script started.
    1/13/2014 1:12 AM - Preparing deployment of ContinuousDeploy to testLocalAzure
    for default with Subscription ID .
    1/13/2014 1:12 AM - Deployment exists in testLocalAzure.  Upgrading deployment.
    1/13/2014 1:12 AM - Upgrading Deployment: In progress
    Set-AzureDeployment : CurrentStorageAccountName is not set. Use
    Set-AzureSubscription subname -CurrentStorageAccountName storageaccount to set
    it.
    At C:\scripts\WindowsAzure\PublishCloudApp.ps1:78 char:22
    +     $setdeployment = Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -Slot $slot -Package
    $packageL ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AzureDeployment], Argumen
       tException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.
       Commands.ServiceManagement.HostedServices.SetAzureDeploymentCommand

    1/13/2014 1:12 AM - Upgrading Deployment: Complete, Deployment ID: 1d90a71030f4
    437bab45b21de76ec308
    1/13/2014 1:12 AM - Created Cloud Service with URL http://testlocalazure.clouda
    pp.net/.
    1/13/2014 1:12 AM - Azure Cloud Service deploy script finished.
    PS C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>
```

This is script, which I call:

```
            Param(  $serviceName = "",
                $storageAccountName = "",
                $packageLocation = "",
                $cloudConfigLocation = "",
                $environment = "Staging",
                $deploymentLabel = "ContinuousDeploy to $servicename",
                $timeStampFormat = "g",
                $alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments = 1,
                $enableDeploymentUpgrade = 1,
                $selectedsubscription = "default",
                $subscriptionDataFile = ""
             )



        function Publish()
        {
            $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot -ErrorVariable a -ErrorAction silentlycontinue 
            if ($a[0] -ne $null)
            {
                Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - No deployment is detected. Creating a new deployment. "
            }
            #check for existing deployment and then either upgrade, delete + deploy, or cancel according to $alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments and $enableDeploymentUpgrade boolean variables
            if ($deployment.Name -ne $null)
            {
                switch ($alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments)
                {
                    1 
                    {
                        switch ($enableDeploymentUpgrade)
                        {
                            1  #Update deployment inplace (usually faster, cheaper, won't destroy VIP)
                            {
                                Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Deployment exists in $servicename.  Upgrading deployment."
                                UpgradeDeployment
                            }
                            0  #Delete then create new deployment
                            {
                                Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Deployment exists in $servicename.  Deleting deployment."
                                DeleteDeployment
                                CreateNewDeployment

                            }
                        } # switch ($enableDeploymentUpgrade)
                    }
                    0
                    {
                        Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - ERROR: Deployment exists in $servicename.  Script execution cancelled."
                        exit
                    }
                } #switch ($alwaysDeleteExistingDeployments)
            } else {
                    CreateNewDeployment
            }
        }

        function CreateNewDeployment()
        {

            write-progress -id 3 -activity "Creating New Deployment" -Status "In progress"
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Creating New Deployment: In progress"

            $opstat = New-AzureDeployment -Slot $slot -Package $packageLocation -Configuration $cloudConfigLocation -label $deploymentLabel -ServiceName $serviceName

            $completeDeployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
            $completeDeploymentID = $completeDeployment.deploymentid

            write-progress -id 3 -activity "Creating New Deployment" -completed -Status "Complete"
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Creating New Deployment: Complete, Deployment ID: $completeDeploymentID"

            StartInstances
        }

        function UpgradeDeployment()
        {
            write-progress -id 3 -activity "Upgrading Deployment" -Status "In progress"
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Upgrading Deployment: In progress"

            # perform Update-Deployment
            $setdeployment = Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -Slot $slot -Package $packageLocation -Configuration $cloudConfigLocation -label $deploymentLabel -ServiceName $serviceName -Force

            $completeDeployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
            $completeDeploymentID = $completeDeployment.deploymentid

            write-progress -id 3 -activity "Upgrading Deployment" -completed -Status "Complete"
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Upgrading Deployment: Complete, Deployment ID: $completeDeploymentID"
        }

        function DeleteDeployment()
        {

            write-progress -id 2 -activity "Deleting Deployment" -Status "In progress"
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Deleting Deployment: In progress"

            #WARNING - always deletes with force
            $removeDeployment = Remove-AzureDeployment -Slot $slot -ServiceName $serviceName -Force

            write-progress -id 2 -activity "Deleting Deployment: Complete" -completed -Status $removeDeployment
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Deleting Deployment: Complete"

        }

        function StartInstances()
        {
            write-progress -id 4 -activity "Starting Instances" -status "In progress"
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Starting Instances: In progress"

            $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
            $runstatus = $deployment.Status

            if ($runstatus -ne 'Running') 
            {
                $run = Set-AzureDeployment -Slot $slot -ServiceName $serviceName -Status Running
            }
            $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
            $oldStatusStr = @("") * $deployment.RoleInstanceList.Count

            while (-not(AllInstancesRunning($deployment.RoleInstanceList)))
            {
                $i = 1
                foreach ($roleInstance in $deployment.RoleInstanceList)
                {
                    $instanceName = $roleInstance.InstanceName
                    $instanceStatus = $roleInstance.InstanceStatus

                    if ($oldStatusStr[$i - 1] -ne $roleInstance.InstanceStatus)
                    {
                        $oldStatusStr[$i - 1] = $roleInstance.InstanceStatus
                        Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Starting Instance '$instanceName': $instanceStatus"
                    }

                    write-progress -id (4 + $i) -activity "Starting Instance '$instanceName'" -status "$instanceStatus"
                    $i = $i + 1
                }

                sleep -Seconds 1

                $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
            }

            $i = 1
            foreach ($roleInstance in $deployment.RoleInstanceList)
            {
                $instanceName = $roleInstance.InstanceName
                $instanceStatus = $roleInstance.InstanceStatus

                if ($oldStatusStr[$i - 1] -ne $roleInstance.InstanceStatus)
                {
                    $oldStatusStr[$i - 1] = $roleInstance.InstanceStatus
                    Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Starting Instance '$instanceName': $instanceStatus"
                }

                $i = $i + 1
            }

            $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot $slot
            $opstat = $deployment.Status 

            write-progress -id 4 -activity "Starting Instances" -completed -status $opstat
            Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Starting Instances: $opstat"
        }

        function AllInstancesRunning($roleInstanceList)
        {
            foreach ($roleInstance in $roleInstanceList)
            {
                if ($roleInstance.InstanceStatus -ne "ReadyRole")
                {
                    return $false
                }
            }

            return $true
        }

        # specify path for Azure module (anyone knows how to configure PSModuleuPath?)
        $env:PSModulePath=$env:PSModulePath+";"+"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell"


        #configure powershell with Azure 1.7 modules
        Import-Module Azure

        #configure powershell with publishsettings for your subscription
        $pubsettings = $subscriptionDataFile
        Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile $pubsettings
        Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount $storageAccountName -SubscriptionName $selectedsubscription

        #set remaining environment variables for Azure cmdlets
        $subscription = Get-AzureSubscription $selectedsubscription
        $subscriptionname = $subscription.subscriptionname
        $subscriptionid = $subscription.subscriptionid
        $slot = $environment

        #main driver - publish & write progress to activity log
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Azure Cloud Service deploy script started."
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Preparing deployment of $deploymentLabel for $subscriptionname with Subscription ID $subscriptionid."

        Publish

        $deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -slot $slot -serviceName $servicename
        $deploymentUrl = $deployment.Url

        Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Created Cloud Service with URL $deploymentUrl."
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Azure Cloud Service deploy script finished."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **-CurrentStorageAccountName** and you used it as -CurrentStorageAccount with Set-AzureSubscription cmdlet. So include **name**.

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue too and it turns out that the active subscription is not updated with the storage info.

After the `Set-AzureSubscription` line you should add
`Select-AzureSubscription $selectedsubscription`

Added a pull request at https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/pull/2115

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much tells you what is going on (bold is mine) -

> 1/13/2014 1:12 AM - Upgrading Deployment: In progress
>       Set-AzureDeployment : CurrentStorageAccountName is not set. **Use
>       Set-AzureSubscription subname -CurrentStorageAccountName storageaccount to set
>       it.**

In the context the script is running the default storage account to use is not set.
You can set it using `Set-AzureSubscription` which I do not see being called anywhere in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Link to original script: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery/

Please, check the Windows Azure Subscription name: in my case it was not "default". 
So you have to edit the **$selectedsubscription** param in the script with the name of the right subscription. You can get it using `Get-AzureSubscription` command.